# error select dinamico - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Tengo un select dinamico que se ejecuta apartir de un campo input, cuando agrego un valor en el input me lo pasa a un campo select, por ejemplo si agrego el numero 5 en el input ese valor carga en el select del 1 al 5 y si posteriormente seleciono el valor 2 de ese select me carga otro select con los números de 2 al 5 y asi consecutivamente se van creando los select hasta que no haya ningun numero a seleccionar, y si en el primer select que me aparece selecciono el numero 5 no me crea mas select, eso es todo lo que hace.

pero tengo dos situaciones que no he podido solucionar:

1. se esta generando de forma automática el primer select con la cantidad de números totales y al generar el otro select me esta quedando el select de los números totales y la idea es que solo me genere el select con los números que yo vaya seleccionando.
2. cuando yo selecciono por ejemplo el 1 dentro de un select el siguiente select no debe cargar el 1 si no a partir del dos y así con todos.

```js
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Pruebas() {
   const [input, setInput] = useState('')
   const [initial, setInitial] = useState(0)
   const [selects, setSelects] = useState([])
 
   const handleClick = (event) => {
     event.preventDefault()
     if (input && !isNaN(input)) {
       setInitial(+input )
       setSelects([+input])
     }
   //  setInput('')
   }
 
   const handleResetClick = (event) => {
     event.preventDefault()
     setSelects([])
   }
   
   const handleSelectClick = (event) => {
     console.clear()
     event.preventDefault()
     const options = event.target.value
     let newSelects = []
     if (options && !isNaN(options)) {
       newSelects = [+options, ...selects]
       newSelects = newSelects.filter((item, pos, arr) => !pos || item != arr[pos - 1])
       setSelects(newSelects)
     }
   }
 
   const getOptions = (options) => {
     let result = Array.from({length: options}, (_, i) => i + 1)
     if (options < initial) {
       result = Array.from({length: initial - options + 1}, (_, i) => i + options)
     }
     result.sort((item, pos) => item - pos)
     return result
   }
 
   return (
     <>
       <hr />
       <input placeholder='Equipos por grupo' value={input} 
               onChange={event => setInput(event.target.value)} />
       <button onClick={handleClick}>Agregar Equipos por grupo</button>
       <button onClick={handleResetClick}>Reiniciar</button>
       <hr />
       {selects.map((select) => (
         <>
           <br />
           <span></span>
           <select  value={select} onChange={handleSelectClick} class="form-control">
             <option value='no' selected>
               Equipos por grupo
             </option>
             {
               getOptions(select).map((item, index) => (
                 <option key={index} value={item}>
                 {item}
                 </option>
               ))
             }
           </select>
         </>
       ))}
     </>
   )
 }
```

Comment: alguien que me colabore no he podido avanzar

Comment: Cuando yo inicio por ejemplo con el valor 3, se crea el `select` con [3,2,1] luego con los demás `select` se muestra el comportamiento deseado. A que te refieres con un `select` con los números totales? saludos

Comment: osea por ejemplo en el input coloco el valor 3 este valor se genera en el primer select pero lo que necesito es que desde ahi se genere los demas select y de forma predeterminada esta quedando guardado el select con los 3 valores, osea que queden guardados los selects desde el momento que selecciono la cantidad de números en el primer select.

Comment: @Giovanny imagino que a medida que se van seleccionando los valores en el select, van desapareciendo para que no se puedan volver a elegir no?

Comment: si, pero al principio por defecto queda seleccionado el primer select que viene con todos los valores y la idea es que solo se vayan cargando los que uno va seleccionado y otro error que hay es que por ejemplo el ultimo numero que queda ejemplo el numero 5 al seleccionarlo aparece de nuevo todos los valores cuando se van generando los selects de forma dinamica

Comment: hola envio un video explicándote en si lo que me falta y no he podido hacer , si me puedes ayudar te lo agradecería - https://youtu.be/6FFmM2xY0nw

Comment: @Giovanny yo creo que mi gran problema para poder ayudarte, es que no entiendo del todo lo que quieres realizar :( Si quieres envíame un correo y nos coordinamos para darte una mano _(paulo.1989.dev@gmail.com)_

Comment: listo, muchas gracias ya le escribo.

Comment: Te comparti en sandbox

Comment: por favor si alguien me puede ayudar con este punto es parecido a lo que se hizo en esta pregunta, les agradecería : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/483316/no-he-podido-agregar-select-dinamicos-reactjs

Answer (score 1):

Añadi el codigo usando hooks
Te dejo el algorito funcionando en este link https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-christian-wqxo2

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";
let initialState = {
  first: null,
  arraySelect: []
};
const Test = () => {
  const [arraySelect, setarraySelect] = useState(initialState.arraySelect);
  const [numberIni, setnumberIni] = useState(initialState.first);

  const getArray = (value) => {
    let arr = [];
    {
      let reco = Math.round(numberIni - parseInt(value));
      console.log(reco);

      if (parseInt(value) == numberIni) {
        return false;
      }
      Array(reco)
        .fill(1)
        .map((value2, key) => {
          arr.push(parseInt(value) + parseInt(key + 1));
        });
    }
    return arr;
  };
  const setSelect = (value) => {
    let isArray = getArray(value);
    if (isArray) {
      setarraySelect([...arraySelect, isArray]);
    }
  };
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setnumberIni(event.target.numberIni.value);
  };
  const resetForm = () => {
    setnumberIni(null);
    setarraySelect([]);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input name="numberIni" type="number" />
        <input type="submit" value="Generar select" />
      </form>
      {numberIni && (
        <div>
          <select onChange={(e) => setSelect(e.target.value)} name="" id="">
            <option value="seleccione">Seleccione</option>
            {Array(parseInt(numberIni))
              .fill(1)
              .map((value, key) => {
                return <option value={key + 1}>{key + 1}</option>;
              })}
          </select>

          {Array(parseInt(numberIni))
            .fill(1)
            .map((value, key2) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  {arraySelect[key2] && (
                    <>
                      <select
                        onChange={(e) => setSelect(e.target.value)}
                        name=""
                        id=""
                      >
                        <option value="seleccione">Seleccione</option>
                        {arraySelect[key2].map((value, key3) => {
                          return (
                            <option value={arraySelect[key2][key3]}>
                              {arraySelect[key2][key3]}
                            </option>
                          );
                        })}
                      </select>
                    </>
                  )}
                </div>
              );
            })}
        </div>
      )}

      {numberIni && (
        <input onClick={() => resetForm()} type="button" value="Reiniciar" />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: Tu respuesta puede mejorar si a parte del código mencionas los cambios que realizaste y que dan solución a la pregunta. Te invito a ver [answer].

Comment: buen dia, esta bien el algoritmo pero quitaste el input que es donde uno coloca el numero que se genera en el select y quitaste el boton de reiciciar.

Comment: Ya te añadi estas funcionalidades

Comment: muchas gracias christian camilo, ahora tengo otro inconveniente si me puedes ayudar se lo agradecería:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/483316/no-he-podido-agregar-select-dinamicos-reactjs

Comment: por favor si alguien me puede ayudar con este punto es parecido a lo que se hizo en esta pregunta, les agradecería : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/483316/no-he-podido-agregar-select-dinamicos-reactjs

Comment: ya puede avanzar bastante con esta pregunta solo me falta algo muy puntual si alguien me puede colaborar : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/483819/select-dinamicos-desordenados-reactjs

Comment: hola cristian camilo, tengo un inconveniente con el codigo que me ayudo , necesito que el codigo haga lo mismo pero en vez de ir sumando los select hasta llegar al valor maximo el input ahora necesito que lo select se vayan restando hasta llegar a uno, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69684272/select-descending-on-reactjs