# no he podido agregar select dinamicos - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

**buen dia , no he podido agregar un select dinámico que ya esta funcionando pero no he podido integrarlo en mi proyecto:
envio un video donde explico lo hay y lo que no he podido hacer, les agradezco si me pueden ayudar
He intentado de muchas formas y no he podido lograrlo, en el video hago la explicación lo mas claro posible. Ya tengo casi toda la funcionalidad lista pero no he podido poner a funcionar el algoritmo de forma completa.**

explicación:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GipZjYNX4b4&ab_channel=videos

proyecto actual :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'


 function Esquema_torneo(props) {

  //divisores
  const [input, setInput] = useState()
  const [values, setValues] = useState([])

  //multiplicacion select -1

  const [input_multi, setInput_multi] = useState()
  const [values_multi, setValues_multi] = useState([])

  const getMods = number => {
     let aux = []
     for (let x = 1; x <= number; x++) {
        if (number % x === 0) {
           aux.push(x)
        }
     }
     return aux
  }

//multiplicacion select -1
  const handleClick_multi = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setValues_multi([(+input_multi - 1), ((+input_multi - 1) * 2), ((+input_multi - 1) * 2 * 2)])
   // setInput_multi('')
}

//divisores
  const handleClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault(); //esto previene que el form se mande.
     if (+input > 0) {
      const mods = getMods(+input).filter(x => x !== +input)
        setValues(mods)
     }
    // setInput('')
  }


    return (
        
        
        
            
              <div className="col-sm-12">
                  
    
              <div class="card card-primary">
                  
                  <div class="card-header">
                    <h3 class="card-title">3. ESQUEMA DEL TORNEO - FASE 1</h3>
                  </div>

                  
                
                  <div class="card-body">
                      
                  <form>


<br/>
    


      <div class="row">
          <label>Torneo Lukas Mayores de 40 Años
</label>
     
          <div class="col-sm-3">
    
      <input placeholder='# Equipos inscritos' type="number" className="form-control" value={input} onChange={event => setInput(event.target.value)} />
          <button onClick={handleClick} className="btn btn-info">Activar grupos</button>
      </div>
      

     


      <div class="col-sm-3">
      <select name='tipo_cancha' class='form-control'>
             <option value='no' selected>
                 Seleccionar grupos
             </option>
             {values.map((item, index) => (
                <option key={index} value={item}>
                   {item}
                </option>
             ))}
          </select>
 

      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="number" placeholder='Equipos por grupos' class="form-control" value={input_multi} onChange={event => setInput_multi(event.target.value)}  />
            <button className="btn btn-info" onClick={handleClick_multi}>Activar equipos por grupos</button>

      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3">

      <select name='tipo_cancha' class='form-control'>
                <option value='no' selected>
                Seleccionar Juegos por equipos
                </option>
                {values_multi.map((item, index) => (
   <option key={index} value={item}>
      {item}
   </option>                 
))}
            </select>

     
 

      </div>


    

      
    </div>
    <br/>

    

    <br />

   



                      


 

      <div class="col-sm-12">

          



</div>


 

  </form>
                  </div>
                 
                </div>
    
    
                
    
          </div>
    
       


    )

}



export default Esquema_torneo
```

Código 2:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-christian-wqxo2?file=/src/App.js:1008-1157

Comment: si alguien me puede ayudar se los agradecería...

Comment: no he podido solucionar , alguien que me pueda colaborar.

Comment: ya puede avanzar bastante con esta pregunta solo me falta algo muy puntual si alguien me puede colaborar : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/483819/select-dinamicos-desordenados-reactjs